# How can i convert NSNamedColorSpace colour to NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace colour? then to CGColor in lion?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, nscolor

I want to convert any colour which comes as a input to CGColor . Everything works fine until in comming colour is of space NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace, but when it is of type NSNamedColorSpace (NSSelectedMenuItemColor) it won't produce a proper result in lion.
Tried getting patternImage too but NSNamedColorSpace colours does not respond to that API.
I am sure many had faced this issue,
kindly help me if you can.

Part of code where i am trying to covert

```
       if ([colorSpaceName isEqualToString:NSNamedColorSpace])
        {
            color = [color colorUsingColorSpace:[NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace]];
        }

        NSColorSpace *colorSpaceNS = [color colorSpace];
        colorSpace = [colorSpaceNS CGColorSpace];

        size_t numberOfComponents = CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents(colorSpace);
        CGFloat components[numberOfComponents];
        [color getComponents:components];
        requiredColor = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, components);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code basically what you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to write category on NSColor which returns the CGColor for any NSColor input in LION. One perticuler case is input colour is NSSelectedMenuItemColor which is of type NSNamedColorSpace. and i wonder how to convert it to CGColor.

Comment: Can you please paste your code?

Comment: Pasted my code too..any updates?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (OS X 10.8 or later):

```
if ([colorSpaceName isEqualToString:NSNamedColorSpace])
        {
            color = [color colorUsingColorSpace:[NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace]];
        }

        requiredColor = [color CGColor];
```

Second way (OS X 10.0 or later):

```
if ([colorSpaceName isEqualToString:NSNamedColorSpace])        {
      color = [color colorUsingColorSpace:[NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace]];
}

CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
[color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

requiredColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(red, green, blue, alpha);
```

Comment: CGColor Api is not in lion. that was the whole point of the question.

Comment: I enlarged my answer.

Comment: Even the result of this is almost smiler to what i got from my code. no improvements, i am trying to convert NSSelectedMenuItemColor.

Comment: Please provide more info, especially how you get NSSelectedMenuItemColor. I don't understand your question. Add some code...